# Why i have to assign NULL to pointer after freeing allocated memory?

Tags: c, null, free, allocation

My question is why i have to assign NULL to pointer after freeing allocated memory?

```
free(*ptr);
*ptr = NULL;
```

I mean situation like this, why it is necesssary?

Comment: Not doing it would make your pointer reference a deallocated chunk of memory, meaning you would have a dandling pointer, which is really dangerous.

Comment: It also means you can `free` it again without harm, because `free(NULL)` does nothing.

Comment: I assume you actually meant `ptr=NULL;`. What you wrote means that you access `*ptr` after the memory was free which is illega.l.

Comment: It's not necessary. It's useful. Sort of.